# How can I put a clickable link in an NVD3 tooltip?

Tags: d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

NVD3 tooltips, by default, disappear when you mouse off *the point the tooltip is associated with*. My spec calls for a clickable link in the tooltip, so I need the tooltip to stay visible while the user mouses thru it, and only disappear when the mouseout *the tooltip*, not the underlying point.

**How can I do this?** Examples I've seen deal with making custom tooltips with d3, and I'm trying to work with NVD3 stuff where possible.

Additional info: in order to support ie9 I'm using `NVD3-1.2.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: nvd3 1.8.1

Hi,

I was using angular-nvd3 and I wanted to make the tooltip clickable because I had the requirement of adding a link on it. Anyway, I was struggling with it so I had a look to the sources. Then, I noticed the only & minimum way to do that was removing or commenting the line 520 in nv.1.8.1.d3.css

```
/*pointer-events: none;*/
```

Finally, you will have a clickable link in your tooltip. I am attaching a plunkr because I think can be useful for everyone who wants to get this functionality

http://embed.plnkr.co/n9QWBNHRDVEt4tuQh1fO

Bye